# 31 QButtonGroups of 5 radio buttons iteration

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer, qradiobutton

need some assistance please.
im making an interface for some equipment we have at work, the actual comms and info required are easy to sort. Im trying to reduce the code size by iterating the radiobutton check.This is the GUI.

GUI Display

[image]

I want to use the radio buttons to select which alarm is assocaited with each output. At present im going th have to write 31 functions that will all do the same job of scanning to detect which radio button is selected.

```
    for i in range (len(Coms)):
        self.Com_List.addItem(Coms[i])
    self.DA1_7.setChecked(True)
    self.Com_List.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.COMselect) 
    self.Baud_Com.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.Baudselect) 
    self.DA1.buttonClicked.connect(self.Row1)
    self.DA2.buttonClicked.connect(self.Row2)
    self.DA3.buttonClicked.connect(self.Row3)   

    self.SerialCon_Btn.clicked.connect(setSerial)       
    self.SysInfo_Btn.clicked.connect(self.GetSysInfo)

def Row1(self):
    indexOfChecked = [self.DA1.buttons()[x].isChecked() for x in range(len(self.DA1.buttons()))].index(True)
    print indexOfChecked +1
def Row2(self):
    indexOfChecked = [self.DA2.buttons()[x].isChecked() for x in range(len(self.DA2.buttons()))].index(True)
    print indexOfChecked +1
def Row3(self):
    indexOfChecked = [self.DA3.buttons()[x].isChecked() for x in range(len(self.DA3.buttons()))].index(True)
    print indexOfChecked +1
```

The QButtonGroups are Labelled DA1-DA31 inclusive, i cant get my head round how i can use one function and iterate it.
Im using QT designer for the gui and calling the UI file using qtCreatorFile to call it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: provide the .ui file

Answer (score 0):

Not really ans answer but eneded up using a list box to select the multiple items